# Render Component A in Component B Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

How can I render component in another component?
This component works fine when not rendering in another...

**Exception:**

[image]

**Dashboard.module.ts**

[image]

**App.module.ts**

[image]

**Dashboard:**

Cannot use component here.

[image]

**SiteComponent.ts**

[image]

**Finally sitecomponent has table**

```
<table datatable datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
       [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" >
<caption> </caption>
   <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Customer No.</th>
      <th>Meter S.No</th>
      <th>Modem ID</th>
      <th>Instrument Type</th>
      <th>Instrument No</th>
      <th>Region</th>
      <th>Zone</th>
       <th>Category</th>
       <th>SP Id</th>
       <th>SP Type</th>
      <th>Meter Type</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Site ID</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let tbl of sites$">

<td>{{tbl.site_name}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.customer_id}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.meter_serial_no}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.device_id}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.device_type}}</td>


<td>{{tbl.Evc_Serial_No}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.region_name}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.zone_name}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.Category}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.Service_Point_Id}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.Serv_Point_type}}</td>

<td>{{tbl.meter_type}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.Address}}</td>
<td>{{tbl.site_id}}</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component is only used within `DashboardModule`, remove it from your `app.module` and enusre it is in both the `declarations` array of your DashboardModule and `entryComponents`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ SiteSearchComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ SiteSearchComponent ]
})
```

Comment: this error was thrown "Component SiteSearchComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module".

Comment: put your dashboard module into the import section of app module

Comment: thank you very much @dince for rapid response , it solved my problem ! vote up from me